# DSP microchip in Phonak products

Tags: audio-processing, adaptive-algorithms

Does anyone know which chips Phonak uses in their products to run the DSP algorithms?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some specific examples of the products of interest?

Comment: For example these ones:
https://auzen.com/products/auzen-phonak-audeo-paradise-50-pr-t-confort-robustesse
https://auzen.com/products/aides-auditives-phonak-audeo-lumity-l50-rt

Comment: It would probably take a teardown of one. I highly doubt an engineer from the company itself would be allowed to tell you. Also, let's be realistic here: how would that knowledge benefit you? The interesting part is what happens on that controller, be it a classical DSP, a microcontroller, some ASIC (which by the way would not be that unlikely in a tightly integrated device like that), configurable logic or the combination thereof.

Comment: I am trying to assess whether such a hearing aid (at least some functionality) can be realized using a microcontroller, e.g. ARM or TMS320 (using a development board, e.g. Raspberry Pi)

Comment: You asked a very different question though :-) The answer for "some" functionality is yes,  that's possible. But the raspberry pi is not a development for neither the tms320 series not for any arm processors. So, that really just opened up more questions. I think it might be wise to ask a new question, where you describe very precisely (and I mean that, because you left that really unclear, what functionality you consider specifically) what the functionality you want to achieve is, and ask what you actually care about: for example, whether an msp320 would be able to run the necessary Software.

Comment: I see no reason why the DSP algorithms could not be run on a general-purpose processor. The key point is to know these algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Most companies will consider this type of information confidential, so it will be hard to come up with a parts number. Hearing aides processors are extremity constrained in terms of size, power consumptions, processing power, memory, interfaces, etc. While some chis are available off-the-shelf, many larger hearing aid companies use  their own custom silicon.

> I am trying to assess whether such a hearing aid (at least some functionality) can be realized using a microcontroller, e.g. ARM or TMS320 (using a development board, e.g. Raspberry Pi)

Depends on what the functionality is. Most ARMs and DSPs will have vastly higher performance in terms of CPU and memory than a dedicated hearing aid chip. Things are more murky when it comes to bit-exact modelling of fixed point algorithms and anything that requires super latency and tight feedback loops. These things are typically more dependent on the actual hardware being used.

It also depends on the class of hearing aid, i.e. behind the air, in the ear or cochlea implant. These have fairly different requirements, functionality and processor classes.

This being said: Phonak does have a collaboration with Advanced Bionics (https://www.advancedbionics.com/com/en/campaign/phonak-solutions.html)